# Xcode not building for multiple architectures

Tags: xcode

I’m trying to follow this tutorial: https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/

In my framework, I have

```
Valid Architectures arm64 armv7 armv7s

BuildActiveArchitecture Only 
Debug No
Release No
```

I have tried both Skip Install setting to No and Yes.  When I make a build for Release or Debug and I run

```
lipo -info MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
```

I keep getting

```
Non-fat file: MyFramework.framework/MyFramework is architecture: arm64
```

This is Xcode 9.2.  Why isn’t Xcode generating armv7 and armv7s builds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have your "minimum deployment version" set to 11.2 (or whatever Xcode 9.2 has set by default).

If you reset your "minimum deployment version" for your framework down to 9.0 or 10.0, you should pick up the additional (32-bit) architectures.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I did not set the Architectures (ARCHS), which are hidden by default in the Build Settings (at the top where it says "Basic", "Customized", and "All", you need to click "All" to see it).

Its default value is "Standard Architectures ($ARCHS_STANDARD)", which for iOS means arm64 and armv7.

The capital letter names are the ones you'll see if you locate and edit your project's `project.pbxproj` file with a regular text editor. The ones that have their default values will be completely absent from the file (or the relevant section thereof).